# Android Studio get data from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I had some problem about get data from sqlite different database.One database that save user's name and phone and they can update as they like. While another is house information but also contain user's name and phone.
My problem is i just realize that the phone that had been update in user database is not same with phone that previous store in house database. So i wanna call the user's phone from user database and use for phone call function and message function. But it does not work.And i trying to match the fullname that in user database with house database to call the phone data but still cant.

here is my call and message function

```
public class HouseDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etAddress,etDetail,etPhone;
TextView txType,txProperty,txPrice,txState,txTitle,txOther,txSize,txFullname;
ImageButton bPhone,bMessage;
String type,property,price,state,address,title,other,size,detail,fullnames,fullname,phone;
HousesDB db = new HousesDB(this);
Houses houses;
DatabaseOperations Udb = new DatabaseOperations(this);
PersonalData profileInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_house_detail);

    txType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txTypes);
    txProperty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txProperty);
    txPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txPrice);
    txState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txState);
    etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    txTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txTitle);
    txOther = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txOther);
    txSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txSize);
    txFullname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txFullname);
    etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    etDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDetail);
    bPhone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bPhone);
    bMessage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bMessage);

    fullnames = txFullname.getText().toString();
    type = txType.getText().toString();
    property = txProperty.getText().toString();
    price = txPrice.getText().toString();
    state = txState.getText().toString();
    address = etAddress.getText().toString();
    title = txTitle.getText().toString();
    other = txOther.getText().toString();
    size = txSize.getText().toString();
    detail = etDetail.getText().toString();
    phone = etPhone.getText().toString();


    Intent i = getIntent();
    property = i.getStringExtra("house_property");
    txProperty.setText(property);

    houses = db.getInfo(property);

    txType.setText(houses.getTypes());
    txFullname.setText(houses.getFullname());
    txPrice.setText(houses.getPrice());
    txState.setText(houses.getState());
    etAddress.setText(houses.getAddress());
    txTitle.setText(houses.getTitle());
    txOther.setText(houses.getOther());
    txSize.setText(houses.getSize());
    etDetail.setText(houses.getDetail());


    this.fullnames = fullname;
    profileInfo = Udb.getNumber(fullname);
    etPhone.setText(profileInfo.get_phone());


    bPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent callIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + etPhone));
            startActivity(callIntent);

        }
    });

    bMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + etPhone)));
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my user database that get the phone number

```
  public PersonalData getNumber(String fullname)
{
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "select FullName,Phone from "+ Table_NAME;
    Cursor CR = SQ.rawQuery(query,null);
    String a;
    PersonalData info = new PersonalData();

    if (CR.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            a = CR.getString(0);
            if (a.equals(fullname)) {
                info._phone = CR.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }while (CR.moveToNext());
    }
    return info;
}
```

Comment: Intead of `if (a.equals(fullname))` condition which is in `getNumber()` method use `if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(fullname))`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
        a = CR.getString(0);
        if (a.equals(fullname)) {
            info._phone = CR.getString(1);
            break;
        }
```

with

```
        a = CR.getString(CR.getColumnIndex("Fullname"));
        if (a.equals("FullName")) {
            info._phone = CR.getString(CR.getColumnIndex("Phone"));
            break;
        }
```

your data gotten by `query` maybe not be ordered as you want,in your case that is, the result maybe not in "Fullname,Phone",so you should use `getColumnIndex()` to get data for each column.

Comment: The `getColumnIndex()` method takes a `String` argument, which would be `"FullName"` in this case.

Comment: the parameter is the name of column string,I think you want set fullname in database to a,so its' `Fullname`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm talking about the first line in the second code block. The `getColumnIndex()` call there has no argument.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public PersonalData getNumber(String fullName) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String table = "YOUR TABLE NAME";
    String[] columns = {
        "FullName" ,
        "Phone"
    };
    Cursor cursor = database.query(table , columns , null , null , null , null , null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
    PersonalData info = new PersonalData();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(0);
        if (name.equals(fullName)) {
            info._phone = cursor.getString(1);
            break;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return info;
}
```